# Compilation failed to complete : Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$zza

Tags: android

When compiling the project i get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
...
...
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
...
...
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$zza
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
...
...
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$zza
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
```

these are some dependencies,i think that may cause error

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Comment: The dependencies mix version 7.3.0 and 10.2.1 of Play Services, which is not recomended. What version of Android Studio are you using? If you take these dependencies into Android Studio 3.5.0 Canary 4, then you will get the error 'All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)'.

Comment: thank you @sgjesse